# Css for table td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I created an HTML page and I used table, but i have a problem in first TD on top and I get a empty space.

[Demo](http://prntscr.com/ddoi8q).

My Table Style

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="" width="25%">
        <table cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src="/avatar/thumb/1479077526.png" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>und3rc00d3</strong>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>UserID: <strong>1</strong>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <br>
        <div id="akt">
          <div style="overflow-y:scroll; height:640px;">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Aktivitetet e fundit</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>............
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For the first TD I tried to style with: `position: absolute;` but again it did not  work http://prntscr.com/ddom11

Comment: try `absolute`.

Comment: i tryed <td style="positon: absulute;"> but again dont work http://prntscr.com/ddom11

Comment: read carefully: ABSOLUTE - not absUlute

Comment: sorry i writte wrong in my coment i add absolute but dont work

Comment: If this isn't an email template, then tables should only be used for tabular data - not layout... and you shouldn't really have the need for nested tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding style="vertical-align: top"; as in the code below

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top" width="25%">
                <table cellspacing="0">
                   <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="/avatar/thumb/1479077526.png" style="width:200px; height:200px;"></td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong>und3rc00d3</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>UserID: <strong>1</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
            <br> 
            <div id="akt">
                <div style="overflow-y:scroll; height:640px;">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Aktivitetet e fundit</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>............</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is correct. You cannot see it without borders, but the set height of the second td stretches the first. Default vertical alignment in a td is the middle.